# Is Adobe Flex still worth learning?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, adobe

I am in 4th year of IT school, today we are starting a one month work on Adobe Flex. Having been in the last 4 years mainly web-oriented, this decision (of my school) surprised me a lot, because Adobe is abandoning Flash and Flex with it, mainly because of poor mobile support and performances, and their new project Adobe Edge is clearly the successor of Flash... But it is based on HTML5/CSS3/JS .
Do you think it is still worth learning ?

Comment: +1 for `IT school`. Also, voting to close (see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))

Comment: As primary career focus - I'm not sure. But I think it's worth learning just to know how it works, what it's good for, what paradigms it utilizes etc. Many modern JavaScript frameworks use concepts similar to Flex. 

It's also worth pointing out that you can build mobile (iOS and Android) applications in Flash/Flex, so only the embedding-on-websites part of Flash platform is doomed on mobile.

Comment: Nope, neither Flash or Flex are abandoned. Not having Flash "player" in your favourite mobile device browser (as is used to be) not means the whole "Flash" platform is abandoned. It simply means that Adobe has put all its efforts regarding Flash platform into AIR runtimes. Take care that currently Flex/AIR combination gives you a span of all major desktop and mobile platforms with single codebase. Choosing an developement ecosystem doesn't give you performance "out of the box", it will depend on your code. For the end, any new knowledge you learn makes you a bigger person ;)

Comment: Whether I'd learn Flex or not depends primarily on job prospects in your area. If you're school is covering it you may need to do so for graduation purposes--but it depends how the school works.  Remember the "Flash Platform" is more than just browser based plugin. Adobe AIR allows for building Mobile Applications to deploy to Android & iOS. I believe Browser Flash will become less common as time goes on, but AIR has a chance at winning the mobile cross platform wars. Edge is marketed for designer folk/Creative Suite users; whereas Flex was marketed towards Enterprise Programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think it's worth learning. Most flash developers I know in sweden are having a hard time finding jobs and are thus trying to convert their skills into new languages.

That being said, there's still situations where you'd go into flash and flex as opposed to a different solution, due to time and budget limitations, the weight of the application itself and so on.

Comment: Hey, what's up with the downvote? I just answered the question?

Comment: Make of it what you will: http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/Shockwave-Flash-Embed

Comment: I suspect you got the downvote because you gave an "absolute" answer to a question where thing are more nuanced.

Comment: Most flash site would use SWFObject to embed flash content (re trends link above)

Comment: As an aside there are still a fair amount of jobs for Flash/Flex developers in Silicon Valley. Though it's not the same as it was a few years ago.

Comment: As seen on builtwith.com (link below) flash is decreasing in popularity and by that also usage. The business sector is the one that's currently using the most sites with embedded flash, and this sector is known to be slow when it comes to technological changes. I reckon that there will be a small niche of jobs where flash will be needed for another 7-8 years, but after that it's looking grim, considering the rate of the spreading unpopularity. http://trends.builtwith.com/framework/Shockwave-Flash-Embed